# JS / jQuery - How to load specific HTML element in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to load all table elements from my `index.html` which have the specified class assigned in a variable. Unfortunately the first line of HTML doesn't load correctly.

**My HTML *(example for one table, usually there a few of them)*:**

```
<!-- More HTML stuff -->
<table class="class_TopTable table" id="id_TopTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="id_Remove">Remove 1</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="id_Title"><B>Title 1</B></div>
      <div id="id_Content">Content 1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- More HTML stuff -->
```

**My Javascript:**

```
var all_class_TopTable = "";
$('.class_TopTable').each(function(){
      all_class_TopTable += $(this).html();
})
```

After this JS is run, the variable of `all_class_TopTable` containts following HTML:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="id_Remove">Remove 1</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="id_Title"><B>Title 1</B></div>
      <div id="id_Content">Content 1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Where the first line is different as my real html.
I expect in the beginning `<table class="class_TopTable table" id="id_TopTable">` and in the end `</table>`.

But the result is in the beginning `<tbody>` and in the end `</tbody>`.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Tables contain thead, tfoot and tbody elements. If you do not specify, than whatever rows that are in the table are in the tbody element. You are reading the HTML of the table so it selects all the children, hence why you get tbody. If you want the table tag, than you need to read the [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `outerHTML` property to capture the element itself along with its descendants.

```
all_class_TopTable += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
```

As the `html` method only captures its descendants, it wraps it with `tbody`.

Comment: Note that it is not the `html` method that wraps it with `tbody`. `tbody` is added at the moment the DOM is built.

Comment: @trincot Good point. Looks like I interpreted it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the *inner* HTML of the `table` node(s), which excludes the `table` node(s) itself.

You could wrap all the content in a `div` and then get its `html`:

```
var all_class_TopTable = $('<div>').append($('.class_TopTable').clone()).html();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I know why it doesn't work and how to solve it.